# How do I execute a sudo command without a password?

Tags: 13.04, sudo

I have a simple shell script that uses the `killall` command. I would like to run this command without needing to enter my password. I've brought up `visudo` and inserted the following line into it:

```
anthony localhost = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/myscript
```

I close Terminal, reopen it, and issue my script command. I am immediately greeted with a prompt for my password.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: Are you typing `sudo myscript`? If you have edited the sudoers file correctly then you shouldn't need the `sudo` in front of it (and if you put it there, I think it will still prompt you for your password).

if it's something somehow related to `killall` then I will undelete my answer, which turned out to be slightly irrelevant - though in principle `killall` shouldn't need root access, I think... Depends on what process you're killing, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

replace localhost by your hostname or use ALL if your sudoers file is not dispatched on other hosts

```
anthony ALL= (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/myscript
```

edit:
Scripts can be tricked by environment parameters. It is more secure (and easier to use) to sudo the killall command into your script than to sudo the script itself. Full killall command with its parameters can be put into the sudoers file, limiting the sudo killall usage.